# FInd and replace - Java Script / jquery

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, replace, find

What I need to do is to *replace number by name* based on data in array or object.
I know how to do that in PHP.

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$array1 = array('111', '222', '333');
$array2 = array('john','adam','mike');

echo $array2[array_search('222', $array1)];
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/599c839dccf5b3d9101cec2a45d14fc4bce258b1

And what I need is the same in JavaScript.

```
var numbers = ['111', '222', '333'];
var names = ['john','adam','mike'];
var something['222']=  .... ?
```

Comment: Can you edit to describe your problem more? How do numbers map to names?

Comment: I want to ask for '222' and reveive 'adam' in return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var numbers = ['111', '222', '333'];
var names = ['john','adam','mike'];

function rep (val) {
   let i = numbers.indexOf(val)
   return names[i]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to create a map of numbers to names. You have a few options, but the shortest would be with a `reduce`:

```
const converted = array1.reduce(( acc,curr,index) => ({...acc, [curr]:array2[index]}), {})
```

```js
const numbers = ['111', '222', '333'];
const names = ['john','adam','mike'];

const converted = numbers.reduce(( acc,curr,index) => ({...acc, [curr]:names[index]}), {})

console.log(converted['222']) // -> 'adam'
```

Comment: Hello Will, thanks, this also works, but "codeR developR" answer was easier for me. Thank you for contribution